# Quick Sort in C++ not working when middle element chosen as pivot

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, quicksort

I have tried an implementation of quick sort in c++. I am facing an issue. If I arbitrarily select the pivot as the first or the last element, the program runs fine, but if I select the middle element as the pivot ( (beg + end)/2 ), then the output is not perfectly correct. Most elements are in sorted order, only some are in random, incorrect places. The following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void quickSort(int[], int, int);
void print(int);

void print(int n) //prints 50 random numbers in a file
{
    ofstream of("List.txt");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x = rand() % 50 + 1;
        of << x << endl;
    }
    of.close();
}

int sortf() //calls the quicksort function and sends it array of elements which
{           //were previously stored in the file and outputs sorted values to another file
    int arr[50];
    int n = 50;
    ifstream f("List.txt");
    int counter = 0;
    int i;
    while (!f.eof() && counter < 50)
    {
        f >> arr[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    quickSort(arr, 0, 49);
    ofstream of("ListOut.txt");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        of << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int start, int end) //applies quicksort algorithm
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        int a = start;
        int b = end;
        int p = arr[(a + b) / 2];
        int x = (a + b) / 2;
        int temp;
        while (a < b)
        {
            while (arr[b] > p)
            {
                b--;
            }
            while (arr[a] <= p && a <= b)
            {
                a++;
            }
            if (a < b)
            {
                temp = arr[b]; //swapping left and right position elements
                arr[b] = arr[a];
                arr[a] = temp;
            }
        }

        temp = arr[b]; //bringing pivot in the middle, so that
        arr[b] = arr[x]; //elements smaller than pivot are to the left
        arr[x] = temp; //and elements greater than pivot are to the right
        quickSort(arr, start, b - 1);
        quickSort(arr, b + 1, end);
    }
}

int main()
{
    print(50); //printing 50 numbers in the file
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    sortf();
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    cout << "\nTime taken:\n" << duration; //outputs time taken for input, sorting and output.
}
```

The output file after execution contains the following list of elements:

```
3 16 7 9 25 12 10 12 13 14 24 18 13 16 18 18 21 19 20 20 22 22 23 23 24 27 27 28 30 28 30 30 31 33 34 35 36 41 36 37 37 37 38 41 43 43
44 44 49 50
```

Please help me in correcting my code as I have wasted quite a lot of hours on this little problem.

Comment: 1. Pick a specific small-sized array (maybe 5 elements) that gets partitioned incorrectly.  2. Run through line by line to see where it goes wrong. 3. ??? 4. Profit.

Comment: During those hours of self-described wasted time, did you perchance run this through a *debugger*, single-stepping to better understand *why* things break down with middle-element pivot selection?

Comment: Uhm, that's the problem, I am a newbie to C++ and do not know how to use a debugger. Any correction would be appreciated. I need the code ASAP, as I have to implement multiple sorting algorithms and analyze them for a friend's project to be submitted tomorrow and all else are working except quicksort.

Comment: Trying to learn C++ without knowing how to use a debugger is basically programming blind. You need to figure out how to use the debugger "ASAP" as without that you're never going to get anywhere. The basics of a debugger aren't hard to pick up, there's maybe four buttons you need to know how to use. The rest you can learn as you need it.

Comment: I know the importance of learning a gdb or any other debugger, just that I am really not in a position to debug my own code after hours of pondering over it. I learned the algorithms from scratch in a single day and implemented all others successfully except this one. Sorry for being a newbie, but I really cannot figure out the problem myself.

Comment: `while (arr[a] <= p && a <= b)`  This appears to be a problem.  `arr[a]` can be equal to the pivot when you swap with `arr[b]`.

Comment: I'll check that line again. Finally convinced my lazy self to switch to Netbeans and use its debugger. Not so difficult it seems!

Comment: Actually, might be the one before it with the `arr[b]` comparison.  Step by step on a small file should point to the problem.

Comment: @50calrevolver Also, **don't use random numbers** to start with.  All that is going to do is change your data every time you want to run your program when you're trying to fix the problem.  Choose 5, at most 10 **known** numbers to sort, have a piece of paper with the outline as to what is to be done showing and what the partitioning would look like, and see if the program is following what you wrote down on paper, step-by-step.

Comment: Thanks a ton for pointing me out to use a debugger, really worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution myself using the debugger. Refer to the comment in uppercase to know the change made to correct the code. Following is the working code for Quicksort implementation for 10000 input values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void quickSort(int[], int, int);
void print(int);

void print(int n) //prints 50 random numbers in a file
{
    ofstream of("List.txt");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x = rand() % 10000 + 1;
        of << x << endl;
    }
    of.close();
}

void sortf(int x) //calls the quicksort function and sends it array of elements which
{           //were previously stored in the file and outputs sorted values to another file
    int arr[x];
    int n = x;
    ifstream f("List.txt");
    int counter = 0;
    int i;
    while (!f.eof() && counter < x)
    {
        f >> arr[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    quickSort(arr, 0, x-1);
    ofstream of("ListOut.txt");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        of << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int start, int end) //applies quicksort algorithm
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        int a = start;
        int b = end;
        int p = arr[(a + b) / 2];
        int x = (a + b) / 2;
        int temp;
        while (a < b)
        {
            while (arr[b] > p)
            {
                b--;
            }
            while (arr[a] <= p && a <= b)
            {
                a++;
            }
            if (a < b)
            {
                temp = arr[b]; //swapping left and right position elements
                arr[b] = arr[a];
                arr[a] = temp;
            }
        }
        arr[b] = p; //CHANGED THIS ***************
        quickSort(arr, start, b - 1);
        quickSort(arr, b + 1, end);
    }
}

int main()
{
    print(10000); //printing 50 numbers in the file
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    sortf(10000);
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    cout << "\nTime taken:\n" << duration; //outputs time taken for input, sorting and output.
}
```

Thanks for the helpful advice. Really appreciate you guys insisting on using a debugger. Learned something new and really helpful, now my code works fine, for input of 10000 values. Cheers!

Comment: `int arr[x]` -- Note that this is not valid C++.  C++ requires arrays to use a compile-time constant to specify the number of entries, not a variable.  Your program will fail to compile using Visual Studio, and will also fail to compile using `g++` using `-pedantic - Wall` compile options.  If you want to use standard C++, change that to `std::vector<int> arr(x);` and pass `arr.data()` to the functions that still want an `int *`.

Comment: This was just a trial. I will use vectors for the final version of the code.

Comment: Then the trial is not convincing enough to determine if there are any off-by-one boundary condition errors.  You should change to `std::vector` to ensure that silent error is not occurring.  You go out-of-bounds of an array, the behavior is undefined.  You go out-of-bounds with a vector, then you have `at()` to help with determining this.

Comment: Also, your `sortf` function doesn't return a value when it's supposed to return an `int`.  That's undefined behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that, thanks for pointing that one. Damn, I need some sleep now. The vector version is working fine and my friend is happy.